# jquery plain multiline text value with CRLF characters

Tags: jquery, multiline-text-field

I have a Plain Text multi-line value on my SP2013 list.
Text is entered into the box with Line Feed characters.

When I use the jquery command in an attached JS program

```
var Falerts = $("input[id$='FormAlert']").val();
alert(Falerts);
```

no LF characters are displayed are in the alert, purely just text.

How can I extract the full text, complete with any CR / LF characters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Persistence is golden.

```
var FAlerts = $("textarea[Title='FormAlert']").html();
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
 var FAlerts = document.querySelector("textarea[Title='FormAlert']").innerHTML
```

for those who want to do it native JS without the hassle of loading jQuery